# Audio streaming server for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, audio

I have placed some mp 3 files on my websites ftp account which is simple hosting area of website and from iPhone app i am playing the audio mp 3 file which working well.
But i am want to create a stream server for storing 200 songs on to it and stream them from my mobile app.
Do i have to set up a streaming server (i don't even know how streaming server is set up)?